# "Сколько стоит" или "в какую цену"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Эти выражения эквивалентны или лишь одно правильное?

Answer (score 1):

***Сколько стоит*** - нормативно без ограничений.

***"В какую цену"*** - это больше южнорусское разговорное, диалектное даже, чем просторечное.

Причем не очень понятно, откуда оно вообще взялось. Грамматически правильным было бы ***"какой цены [эта вещь]"***, но такая конструкция сама по себе крайне редко используется, а откуда там еще и предлог взялся... Видимо от выражения ***"В какую цену станет/обойдется то-то и то-то"***. Иначе объяснить трудно. При этом "В какую цену обойдется" тоже отдает искусственностью, больше напоминает плохой перевод с какого-нибудь европейского или идиша.

Короче, причин считать "в какую цену" литературно правильным нет никаких.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: *сколько стоит, по какой цене*. *В какую цену* — просторечное.

[См. Грамоту.ру.](http://%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE:%20_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5_.%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC_%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE.)